# Day of the week multi-select UI

Tags: ios, swift, enums, datepicker

I am creating an events app and need to allow the user to select the day of the week, ie. Mon, Tues, Weds,..etc if they want to create a repeating event.

Is there a library/enums or functionality that allows this selection already pre-built? ( in the same way that datePicker is UI is already built?)

Answer (score 2):

[Picker Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html)

Add it in the interface builder, connect the `delegate` and `data source`, and add the following code to the `UIViewController`.

```
let pickerData = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().shortWeekdaySymbols

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: `NSCalendar.currentCalendar().shortWeekdaySymbols`